# Get back default implementation of window.Map in Visualforce page?

Tags: visualforce, javascript

I'm writing Javascript in a Visualforce page. I'm using a third-party library that relies on the standard implementation of `Map`. Unfortunately, SFDC's `main.js` replaces `window.Map` with some non-standard map implementation. Is there some way I can get back the original Map implementation so that third-party libraries that rely on it can work?

Comment: See one technique in the answer to [Native JS Map prototype is overwritten in Visualforce page w/ a header](http://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/103924/native-js-map-prototype-is-overwritten-in-visualforce-page-w-a-header).